# Always using Latex in Anki

Tags: anki

I am "struggling" with the following problem: I don't like the fact that I always have to manually type [latex]...[/latex] on the front and back when adding a card to my deck. As I only use Latex anyways, I would just like to begin typing and have it automatically understood as latex code (i.e. I don't want to write [latex][/latex] every time).

Is there a solution to this problem, or do I just have to live with this minor discomfort? :)

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is more of an anki question than a LaTeX question, but anyways, [this section](https://apps.ankiweb.net/docs/manual20.html#media-&-latex-references) of the anki manual seems to suggest that it's impossible to achieve with templates at least.